# Grid view column arragement

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a problem to show data in gridview in different columns but data is displaying in a single column.

design

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="international_news" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="news_id"  onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">                       
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="news_id"/>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="news_title"/>                            
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="ReadMore" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("news_id")%>'>
                    Read More
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                    
    </Columns>        
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("news_id", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("news_title", typeof(string))});
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr[1].ToString() != "yes")
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr[1].ToString());                        
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of expected outcome and actual outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I am not positive what you are exactly running into - are you saying that the gridview control, when displaying on the HTML page, is only showing one column?  If so, can you tell us what is showing in the column?

Also, I see a problem in your "code behind" - you should not be setting and binding the gridview inside your while loop.  Move it after the loop, and see if that makes a difference in what you are seeing.

---

Okay, so you are seeing two columns at this point - not one (from what I can tell).  At this point, the concern would be the linkbutton not appearing, correct?  Do you see ANY HTML on the page, if you look at the page source, that might be the linkbutton?  If so, can you post what you see?

Also, please let us know if anything changes when you bind the gridview outside of the while loop.

---

It sounds like you are now seeing all three columns at this point, based on your most recent comment.  Are there further issues?  Are you expecting to see something different?  Can you tell us what you are expecting to see versus what you are actually seeing?

Comment: two columns of data from database displaying in a single column of gridview but actually i want to display all column data in different columns of gridview.

Comment: Me seeing three columns in first id and other data, second column empty and third is link button

Comment: actually i want to see id in first column, other data in second column and in last last column link button